# Python3 Help Modules <module> always returns Traceback error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'"

Tags: package-management, python

Python 3.8.10 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I was getting an error saying module not found when importing unasync.  Decided to go to python and access help() and then modules which displays a list of all available modules and confirms that unasync was available.

I then tried the "modules unasync" and received the following output

```
help> modules unasync

Here is a list of modules whose name or summary contains 'unasync'.
If there are any, enter a module name to get more help.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_sitebuiltins.py", line 103, in __call__
    return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 1918, in __call__
    self.interact()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 1945, in interact
    self.help(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 1964, in help
    self.listmodules(request.split()[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 2100, in listmodules
    apropos(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 2194, in apropos
    ModuleScanner().run(callback, key, onerror=onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 2155, in run
    loader = spec.loader
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

any suggestions how I can unravel this situation much appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have such *unasync* package in the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=unasync).
Repology says that it [is available](https://repology.org/project/python:unasync/versions) via [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/unasync/).

So you have to install this package by

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install unasync
```

and then retry to access it and its help.

Comment: I have already installed unasync as you suggest.  I see that I didn't properly explain.  The unasync module is installed (verified by help modules).  The problem is in code when I import unasync I get module not found and when I try help modules unasysnc  i get above error.